# Antenna for ESP32-pico-D4

Tags: arduino, antenna, pcb-antenna, esp32

If I was to make an antenna for BLE for an ESP32-pico-D4 by just making a wide cobber trace (as on the esp32). 
How long and how thick would it have to be?

Comment: This is the exactly the kind of information that you can find rightly in the ESP32 datasheet. BTW, did you want to say "copper", instead of "cobber"?

Answer (score 0):

1/4 of the length is about 30 mm long, I would suggest to have a look at other antennas design and also check about the ohm resistant as it is very important to have a good signal

Here some info about shape and calculation https://hackaday.io/project/19582-bluetooth-wifi-antenna-upgrade/details

Comment: it doesn't say anything about the width of the antenna? and what do you mean by "check about the ohm resistant"